# Rocket Boost Trails Season 4 Rewards Missing

Tags: rocket-league

Last season I managed to win 12 games on diamond and therefore got all the trails up to and including the diamond trail. I could even use it right away! Now, since the Autumn patch I don't have any boost trails besides the standard. Were they removed from the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the trails are causing some stability issues and were temporarily removed until the problem is fixed.

Link: http://www.psyonix.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=39636

> Due to stability issues on some platforms, we are disabling Season 4 Reward Trails until a fix can be deployed.
>
> Thank you for your patience and understanding this weekend.